# How can I detect the source of current in this circuit

Tags: power-electronics, motor-controller

I have designed this inline motor soft starter circuit:

[image: circuit]

The input is switched externally. When it's turned on, the MCU powers up and produces a ramping PWM output which gradually energizes the motor.

Now here's the issue. I need to detect when the input is OFF (for up to 2 seconds). Sampling the positive rail doesn't work because the motor acts as a generator and back powers the circuit.

The simplest solution would be to add a power diode to the positive rail, but that adds cost, voltage drop and heat dissipation so it's not ideal.

Is there a way I can achieve this without additional power handling or specialty components?

I tried sampling the drain of Q1 during the PWM off cycle, but I never got consistent results, probably due inductive voltage spikes.

The input voltage can be from 6 to 24V and the current up to 20A.

Comment: What about to add a MOSFET as diode? It will have much smaller drop voltage and heat.

Comment: (assuming brushed motor) `input is OFF` it should be much easier to detect \$I_{in}\$ from full to none in 1μs than in one second. *never got consistent results sampling the drain* Well, what results *did* you get? Do you need/use the PIC for anything but soft start?

Comment: (At 6 V input, U2 will have one hell of a time supplying 5V given \$U_F\$ of D3. Does not *need* to be a problem with U1, influences switching&conduction behaviour of Q1. Powering U1 for several seconds should be easier from C4 than from C2, especially if U2 was low loss.)

Comment: What is the purpose of the 'soft starter'?

Comment: Hall effect current sensor in series with motor.

Comment: @user263983 I would consider that a specialty component. I looked anyway because I don't want to rule anything out, but the cheapest one I can find is double the cost of any other component in the BOM.

Comment: @greybeard I haven't tested at 6V but the PIC sips power, and the regulator is a LDO. According to the specs it should work. For simplicity and cost the regulator is linear. The problem at c4 is that there is a wide voltage range, so that cap has to withstand 24V, while also supplying enough power for 2 seconds of run time at 6V.

Comment: @PCBCrew That would work, but it would increase the BOM cost a lot. And every mosfet adds logistical issues since I find they go out of production regularly and need engineering time to substitute.

Comment: @greybeard I tried a lot of methods, filters, and protection for sampling q1's drain. I was never able to achieve a signal that corresponded simply to the input state. The results seemed to vary based on the motor load, and PWM value. It even created weird feedback loops and equilibrium states.

Comment: (I'd be tempted to connect a 10k resistor parallel to DS just to prevent funny voltages.) Can you provide a plot or a value list *of samples following input switch off*? (`weird feedback loops and equilibrium states` - is that "off-time sampling" rather than *input switched off*? Wait, the question states that much.)